# Wavefunction for the deuteron's ground state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, nuclear-physics

I was reading **Blatt & Weisskopf's Theoretical Nuclear Physics** (1979) and on the **II.Two-Body Problems at Low Energies** chapter, page 100, they say:

*The wave function for the composite state (the ground state of the deuteron) then is: $$\phi=\phi_S + \phi_D$$*

Why aren't there any normalization coefficients? Shouldn't it be a linear combinations of such states? $$\phi=a\phi_S+b\phi_D$$

Comment: Presumably they absorb those coefficients into the normalizations of the two components. If the s and d components were individually normalized to 1, the yes, you would need the coefficients out in front.